# BDD tests in C# with specFlow. Taking inputs from Excel Application and WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, cucumber, specflow

I'm using an application built on C# that I use through Visual Studio 2012 framework. It launches an Excel spreadsheet, allows user inputs in excel cells (and also Win Forms/dialog boxes etc pop up asking for input), and then perform calculations based on the input and produce results.

I'm trying to use SpecFlow to automate such a testing scenario. Does anyone know of any tutorial etc that could guide me? Does it makes sense of what I am trying to achieve? Can it be done through Cucumber in some way or any other advise? I have ONLY done simple tests in C# with SpecFlow so far that does not involves popping up excel and asking for user inputs.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SpecFlow is just a framework for testing, it does not give you options for `interacting` with excell or WinForms. So the answer will be No, with just SpecFlow alone you can't achieve this.

You will need some 3rd party API that can script excel or WinForms, something similar to Selenium for web browsers. Maybe [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)?

Comment: Thanks. Or may be I should use Cucumber with Iron Ruby? What I actually need is a kind of tutorial which I could follow and I'm just not able to find a good one.

Comment: Using cucumber with ruby will not change anything, you'll be in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

As Liviu M. has stated in his answer, SpecFlow will not make automating excel easier, it will allow you to define you requirements for the application in terms of the behaviour you expect from your application, rather than though unit test.

Specflow provides a framework for defining tests in terms of defined preconditions, actions  and expected behaviours which it executes by converting into unit tests which are run by a unit testing framework.

In order to automate excel you can use the [Excel interop library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and you could then write scenarios like

```
Scenario: Data is processed correctly
     Given excel is started with workbook 'c:\workbook.xls'
     When the users enters 'blah' into cell 'A1'
     Then cell 'B3' should contain text 'BlahBlah'
```

you can then start excel in the Given step definition:

```
[Give("excel is started with workbook '(.*)'")]
public void StartExcel(string workbook)
{
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    excel.Visible = true;        
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbook);
}
```

more information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C)

your when step could then be something like:

```
[When("the users enters '(.*)' into cell '(.*)'")]
public void WhenTheUsersEntersIntoCell(string textValue, string cell)
{
    Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[sheetName];
    worksheet[cell] = textValue;
}
```

This is pseudo code and I'm not certain this line will work: `worksheet[cell] = textValue;` but it should give you an idea of how you can do it, and you should be able to google the rest.

Comment: Thanks Sam. My application would pop up Win form for example, when you press Save As button, you are prompted to enter the file name and directory. How could I automate those things?

Comment: you might be able to use Coded UI Tests to automate some of those parts see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681(v=vs.100).aspx) and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd286726.aspx) or ask a separate question specifically about that.